# Create a new variable in SQL by groupby

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 sql table as follows:

First table t1:

[image]

Second table t2:

[image]

I need to calculate the count of "Number" column based on "Name" column from t1 and merge it with t2.

I wrote following code. But it seems not working

```
select * 
from (
select Name, count(Number) as count
from t1 
 group by Name ) as a
join ( select *
from t2 ) as b
on a.Name = b.Name;
```

Can any one figure out what is wrong ? Thank you very much

Comment: For starters, you have NAME in both tables, so when you write `select name, count(number....`, you should have received an ambiguous column error. Next, when you join, you don't need to join with a select statement in this case. Just join to table2 on name. `select a.name, b.val1, count(a.number) from t1 a join t2 b on .....`

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please provide the desired output for your example.

Comment: @Isolated It's not ambiguous because the subquery only references one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use SUM() instead of COUNT().
Because SUM() sums some integers, while COUNT() counts number of occurencies.

And as also stated in the comments, multiple columns with same names will create conflicts, so you have to select the wanted columns explicit (that is usually a good idea anyway).

You could obtain your wanted endgoal by this query:

```
select 
  SUM(Number),
  t1.Name,
  (select val1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name LIMIT 1) as val1
FROM t1 
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Example in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04dddf/7